# Triple Array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, append

I have an easy code, which just basically creates 3D array and then one specific array in it. I don't know why, but it appends every array in this 3D array.

```
def createTries():
    number = [0]
    row = []
    tries = []
    for i in range (0,9):
        row.append(number)
    for i in range(0,9):
        tries.append(row)
    tries[0][0].append(1)

    print(tries)
    print(tries[0][0][1])
    return tries

createTries()
```

Could anybody please help me make it append this exact array?

**Edit:** Noticed I forgot to translate few of the integers.
Answer I get is:

> [[[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]], [[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]], [[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]], [[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]], [[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]], [[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]], [[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]], [[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]], [[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]]]

But what I expect to get is:

> [[[0,1], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]], [[0], [0], [0], [0],
>   [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]], [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0],
>   [0]], [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]], [[0], [0], [0],
>   [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]], [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0],
>   [0], [0]], [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]], [[0], [0],
>   [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]], [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0],
>   [0], [0], [0]]]

Comment: Include details of the output you get and the output you expect.

Comment: And what is rida? and proovid? The question is not complete as it stands.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to put data in a very nested format. Maybe you should just consider a "flat" list of your Tries... that will make it much easier to look at and pivot in another way later (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat-file_database)

Comment: @AndyG Sorry for the mess. I forgot to translate few of the names. But now they are correct. Also added the output.

Comment: @Magellan88 Thanks for your answer! In long term I'm using this function in a Sudoku solver, so array would be a bit better. This function will start adding all of the tried numbers into the array, so it would not try the same number twice. But still, thanks for the idea, I had not heard before about Flat files. :)

Comment: ahh, if you want to bild a sudoko solver, why don't you think about a numpy array instead: np.ones((9,9,9)).astype("bool"). then you will have a structured array with rows, columns and per cell a True for every number still to try. by summing over a diemnsion you can check how many possibilities still remain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you do

```
row.append(number)
```

you're appending a reference to the *same* list, not making a copy of it. So when you then modify one of those lists, you're modifying all of them. And the same thing happens when you do:

```
tries.append(row)
```

You need to create new lists in the loops.

```
number = [0]
for i in range(9):
    row = []
    for j in range(9):
        row.append(number[:])
    tries.append(row)
```

`number[:]` makes a shallow copy of the `number` list.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is, that every cell of your list points to the same (python) object namely "number". so what you have is a list of lists, that basically points to the same object.

now `tries[0][0].append(1)` appends to that single object in all your lists a "1" and that's what you see.

I'd go with a numpy array of the sort:

```
SudokuFiled = np.ones((9,9,9)).astype("bool")
```

with that everything behaves as you think it would with encoding your possibilities as a T/F vector